# Node.js and IIS on same server binding to port 443

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, iis

I have a Node.js Express.js RESTful web service that I need to host as a Windows Service on a Windows Server that has IIS installed, there are multiple sites configured in IIS using both port 80 and 443.

I have my Node.js REST service configured to use SSL on port 443 and binding that to the DNS record for the service.

What I am struggling with is port binding to 443, when I install the Node.js service on the Windows Server and start the service the configured websites in IIS on port 443 get stopped.

How is it possible to run both IIS and a Node.js server on the same Windows server bound to port 443